# Dispose Tridion Core Service Client in Java

Tags: core-service, sites-9.1

Disposal of the built-in .NET Core Service client is documented here https://docs.rws.com/783502/152021/sdl-tridion-sites-9-1/disposal-of-the-built-in--net-core-service-client

But same documentation not found for the case of Java. Is there anything required to explicitly use in java code for the core service client disposal. Any comments here. thanks

Comment: please refer to this link  https://docs.rws.com/783502/108753/sdl-tridion-sites-9-1/interacting-with-the-core-service-from-java  for more details.

Comment: Hi , Nothing mentioned in this link about disposal of core service client